# Wamp Server Redirects CSS not working

Tags: css, apache, .htaccess, wamp, url-rewrite-module

My wamp server has apache 2.4.27. Using the opera browser.  I have some code that is supposed to open a webpage that makes a video player spin around and some other beginner examples just for my learning. I was looking at .htaccess files for redirecting the to this page if i go to localhost/examples/beginner . I have a .htaccess file that is in the root directory of this file. I also have some css that is stored in the same directory. When I go to the original path for this page(localhost/SQL/pgsql.html) the css works and the video spins and the background image works. When I go to the redirect( localhost/examples/beginner) the page loads just fine but the css doesn't work. The video doesn't spin and the background image doesn't work.

I haven't been able to figure out how to use an absolute path for my css file, I think that is the issue.

```
<html>

<title>learning</title> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href= "rotate.css" type="text/css" />
<table style = "table-layout:fixed" bgcolor="#00FF00" > 

    <CAPTION> I think this table is my first HTML TABLE </CAPTION> 



    <tr>
    <th align = "middle">  Name</th>
    <th> Views</th> 
    </tr>


    <tr align = "justify">
    <td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" ><?php echo $res11; ?></font>
    </td>
    <td>
    <font face="Book Antigua"><?php echo $res12; ?></font>
    </td>
    </tr>



    <tr align = "center">
    <td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $res21; ?></font>
    </td>
    <td>
    <font face="Book Antigua"><?php echo $res22; ?></font>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $res31; ?></font>
    <font face="Book Antigua"><?php echo $res32; ?></font>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $res41; ?></font>
    <font face="Book Antigua"><?php echo $res42; ?></font>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $res51; ?></font>
    <font face="Book Antigua"><?php echo $res52; ?></font>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $res61; ?></font>
    <font face="Book Antigua"><?php echo $res62; ?></font>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<body>  

    <video class="rotate" width="640" height="360" controls autoplay>
    <source src= "\goodmedia\tesvid.mp4" type = "video/mp4">
    </video>


    <img width="250" height="250" src="\goodmedia\blueberries.png">
    </img>

        <img width="400" height="200" src="\media\Dalmatian.jpg"> 
        </img>


    <div><?php echo realpath('/wamp64/www/SQL/rotate.css')?></div>  

</body> 
</html>
```

here is the css file

```
 body{
     background: url([000613].jpg) no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
    font-family: Arial;  
    color: yellow;
 }
.triangle-up {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
}



 .rotate {
    -webkit-animation:spin 5s linear infinite;
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes spin{
     100%{
     -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}}
```

here is the .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^examples/beginner$ SQL/pgsql.php [NC]
```

Comment: Move the `<table> ... </table>` after the `<body>` tag

Comment: Where are you setting values into these variable i.e. `$res11;` etc

Comment: I changed the table to be in the body and it didn’t work still. The variables were from some php code that got data from a postgresql server. I deleted it because it wasn’t relevant. Is my problem with the Apache server doing the redirect? Somehow not getting the rotate.css file like it should be ?